# LLVM find load/store instructions that operate on heap

Tags: c++, llvm, code-analysis, static-analysis, instrumentation

I'm working on some LLVM instrumentation and I would like to identify load and store instructions that write to heap memory.

Right now I am able to identify calls to `malloc` etc. and I can tell when heap memory is being allocated. Is there anything in LLVM IR that distinguishes between loads/stores to stack vs heap? My assumption is that there isn't.

The approach I was thinking of using was to keep track of the memory addresses returned by `malloc` at runtime, and then instrument calls to `getelementptr` where at runtime I see if the base address is one that has been allocated by `malloc`. I would also instrument any loads/stores that use the pointer returned by a `getelementptr` where the instrumentation code would only run if the address is a heap address.

The question I have is how can I identify such loads/stores? Does LLVM construct a data-dependency graph or something of that nature that I can query to identify these instructions? Basically I want to identify all loads/stores that use the pointer returned by a particular `getelementptr` instruction.

Of course, if there is a much easier way to do this please let me know. I'm quite new at this.

Comment: LLVM does not, but you could use a linker script and custom malloc() to divide memory into three zones: that used by global variables, that potentially returned by malloc(), and the stack. You might be able to analyse some/many gep/load/store pairs to identify global access and stack access. That leaves possible heap access for your runtime to check, but with luck your runtime code doesn't need to deal with *many* false positives.

Comment: What resources would you suggest for linker scripts? I haven't worked with them before. Also, I'm a bit unclear as to what the custom malloc would do, and how it would help analyze the gep-load/store pairs. How will a custom malloc help me identify which areas are used by globals and which ones are used by stack?

Comment: You make an initial decision. For example "the first gigabyte belongs to the executable, the next gigabyte is stack space, the third gigabyte is malloc space". The [linker script is how you tell ld to put all global variables in the first gigabyte](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Scripts.html), your custom malloc() has to return addresses in the third gigabyte, and your runtime can just do a single comparison to see whether the address is in the malloc-able part of memory.

Comment: This stuff is weird and unusual, but it's surprisingly simple ;) The main problem is that you won't find any simple tutorials or role models. All you get is curt directions and unhelpful encouragement from antisocial elements such as myself. Good luck.